# Align horizontal lines in projected view of matrix via opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, perspectivecamera

I have two different matrices A (shape 5, 11) and B (shape 5, 2).
I want to have a projected view of each of these matrices.
Unfortunately, the horizontal lines that are separating different values, end up on different heights (~80px vs ~150px).
Can somebody provide some insight why that is / how to fix it?

I am using numpy, matplotlib and opencv and define a desired output width and height.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
output_width, output_height = 1000, 600
```

This generates the image for matrix A.

```
values = 1 + np.random.rand(5, 11).astype("float32")

source_points = np.array(
    [
        [-0.5, -0.5], [10.5, -0.5], [-0.5, 4.5], [10.5, 4.5],
    ], dtype="float32"
)
target_points = np.array(
    [
        [1, 0], [1000, 0], [250, 250], [750, 250],
    ], dtype="float32"
)

transformation = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(source_points, target_points)
warped_values = cv2.warpPerspective(
    values, 
    transformation, 
    (output_width, output_height), 
    borderMode=cv2.BORDER_TRANSPARENT, 
    flags=cv2.INTER_NEAREST
)
plt.imshow(warped_values)
```

[image: matrix A]

This generates the iamge for matrix B.

```
values = 1 + np.random.rand(5, 2).astype("float32")

source_points = np.array(
    [
        [-0.5, -0.5], [1.5, -0.5], [-0.5, 4.5], [1.5, 4.5],
    ], dtype="float32"
)

target_points = np.array(
    [
        [201, 0],  [800, 0], [450, 250], [550, 250],
    ], dtype="float32"
)

transformation = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(source_points, target_points)
warped_values = cv2.warpPerspective(
    values, 
    transformation, 
    (output_width, output_height), 
    flags=cv2.INTER_NEAREST, 
    borderMode=cv2.BORDER_TRANSPARENT
)
plt.imshow(warped_values)
```

[image: matrix B]

Comment: You're using different source and target points for the two plots.  I'm not sure why you are surprised that they warp differently.

Comment: The vanishing point is very different between your two sets of values.  That's why the lines differ.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. That is correct and helped me a lot! :-)